# How to sum numbers in Dataframe based on length of keywords?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample of search engine DataFrame which has 2 columns: entered keyword to search and number of searches of this keyword.
Example:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'keyword': ['one','one two','2','two 34 45', 'ab', 'long 1 4 ab'],
'number of searches': ['4', '9', '1', '2', '7', '1']})
```

I would like to sum how many searches were made (not just count number of words) for keywords which consist of 1 word, 2 words, 3 words, etc. so final result must be like:

```
1 word: 13
2 words: 9
3 words: 2
4 words: 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not need to count, I need to sum based on another column.

Comment: OK, sorry, i've removed my `close` vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way:

first, make sure that your `number of searches` column is of integer data type:

```
df['number of searches'] = df['number of searches'].astype(int)

(df.groupby(df.keyword.str.split().apply(len))['number of searches']
   .sum()
   .to_frame()
   .reset_index()
   .apply(lambda x: '{0[0]} words: {0[1]}'.format(x), axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
0    1 words: 12
1     2 words: 9
2     3 words: 2
3     4 words: 1
dtype: object
```

Comment: Got error: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal. I suppose there is must be closing ' in lambda func?